# When importing items/categories into magento using magmi the buy now button doesn't appear

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I have managed to make a csv which imports my products using magmi into my magento store.
All works well but the buy now buttons don't appear unless I go to the product and click save.
I've tried reindexing or clearing the cache but nothing seems to work.
Any further ideas.

I'm using the up to date magento/magmi.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the importer check the reindexer and the on the fly indexer.
That seems to do the trick!
Richard